Reverse motor direction on the fly using Teensystep RotateControl
I would like to control two stepper motors with a Teensy 4.0 and Teensystep.
The RotateControl class seems great for that.  But I want one motor to continue to rotate until stopped, but the other motor (with an arm attached) should rotate a set angle and then reverse, so it swings back and forth.
(Ideally, the speed of the x coordinate of the tip of the arm would be constant, so it traces back and forth, and the x coordinate has a constant speed, first one way, then the other.)
Maybe the RotateControl class isn't what I need though...
Any suggestions?
I've read the documentation for RotateControl, but don't see the information I'm looking for.
